# Input control is not editable on Multi Modal of react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

I have two Modal Components in my application and on click of edit button in a Modal another Modal will open, and in the second Modal I have input control and its not editable

The following are the files which I used in my application.

import bootstrap css in index.js file as below

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

App.js

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton />
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyButton.js

```js
export default class MyButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            personalInfoModalShow: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        let handlePersonalInfoModalHide = () => this.setState({
            personalInfoModalShow: false
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.setState({
                    personalInfoModalShow: true
                })}
                >
                    Open Modal
                </button>
                <PersonalInfoModal
                    show={this.state.personalInfoModalShow}
                    handlePersonalInfoModalHide={handlePersonalInfoModalHide}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

PersonalInfoModal.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import {Container, Table} from "reactstrap";
import {FaPencilAlt} from "react-icons/fa";
import EditModal from "./EditModal";

export default class PersonalInfoModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: 100,
            name: 'Sam',
            department: 'IT',
            isEditClicked: false,
            editModalShow: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        let handleEditModalHide = () => this.setState({
            isEditClicked: false,
            editModalShow: false
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal
                    show={this.props.show}
                    onHide={this.props.handlePersonalInfoModalHide}
                    size="lg"
                    centered
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="personal-modal-title">
                            Personal Information
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Container fluid>
                            <Table striped responsive size="sm" className="text-center mt-4">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Department</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{this.state.id}</td>
                                <td>{this.state.name}</td>
                                <td>{this.state.department}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div onClick={() => this.setState({
                                        isEditClicked: true,
                                        editModalShow: true
                                    })}
                                    >
                                        <FaPencilAlt />
                                    </div>
                                    {this.state.isEditClicked &&
                                    <EditModal
                                        show={this.state.editModalShow}
                                        handleEditModalHide={handleEditModalHide}
                                        department={this.state.department}
                                    />
                                    }
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </Table>
                        </Container>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

EditModal.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";

export default class EditModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            department: props.department
        };
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const input = e.target;
        const name = input.name;
        const value = input.value;
        this.setState({[name]: value});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal
                    show={this.props.show}
                    onHide={this.props.handleEditModalHide}
                    size="sm"
                    centered
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="edit-modal-title">
                            Edit
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <input style={{width: "35%"}} type="text" value={this.state.department} name="department" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.handleEditModalHide}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => alert("saved")}>
                            Save Changes
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried creating codesandbox, I am able to edit the textbox, what is the issue you are facing. Here is [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-lake-t8o53)

Comment: Can be having modal tabindex problem?

Comment: @tarzenchugh, I am also using the same code, but not working in my system. I have tested the same in different browsers but no luck. What could be the problem? Can you please check the same in your local and let me know?

Comment: Can you create a new project using `create-react-app` with latest npm and node verson and then write the code. Did you check out the sandbox link, is that working fine?

Comment: yeah that link is working fine.... FYI the app is created newly this morning only

Comment: Please update your node and npm versions and then create project using create-react-app

Comment: @tarzenchugh, I have changed my package.json with yours but still no luck

Comment: I have updated the node (v12.9.0) and npm (6.11.1) but still its not working

Comment: @SercanPaspal, Can you please elaborate more on this issue?

Comment: I fixed this with an attribute called "enforceFocus" in Modal